# Previous employer has not rolled over my 401k yet

Tags: united-states, 401k, rollover, job-change

I left a company over 10 months ago and they still haven't rolled over my 401k yet. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Please add more detail to this question as it is currently unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Is there a law stating that rolling over a 401k shouldnt take over a certain amount if months. I could be putting in money but instead im lossing.

Comment: Did you send them a complete request to roll over the 401(k) on the forms that they require be used? Also, often you set up an IRA and delegate the task of getting the funds turned over to them to the new IRA firm. A rollover isn't don't automatically in the absence of a proper and complete request.

Answer (score 2):

For the rollover, you should probably talk to the recipient manager.  This would be your broker or whomever (your new employer if rolling into another 401k).  They should be able to update you on progress and let you know if you need to do anything.

In a comment, you say

> I could be putting in money but instead im lossing.

There is no requirement that an IRA have 401k money in it.  Just put the money in without the existing money.  Eventually the rollover will complete and add that money to whatever you contribute to the IRA.  The rollover should not affect your future contributions in any way.